# How to add more than 1 user role to sub-menu pages

Tags: plugin-development, user-roles, add-submenu-page

I create a plugin with 6 submenu pages. I need 4 of them  to be accessible by administrator and a custom user role i created say 'coach' user. Then the 2 of them to be accessible by administrator and another custom user role 'player'. How would i do that to add 2 user role?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is create 2 custom capabilities and assign both to administrators, one to role *coach* and one to role *player*.

When you create your roles you do something like this:

```
$coach_caps = array(
  'read' => true,
  'something_else' => true,
  'can_open_coach_menu' => TRUE // this is important for your scope
);
add_role( 'coach', 'Coach', $coach_caps );

$player_caps = array(
  'read' => true,
  'something' => true,
  'can_open_player_menu' => TRUE // this is important for your scope
);
add_role( 'player', 'Player', $player_caps );
```

Then assign both capabilities to the administrator role:

```
$roles = new WP_Roles();
$roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'can_open_coach_menu', TRUE);
$roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'can_open_player_menu', TRUE);
```

Now when you add submenu pages:

```
// this is for administrator and coach roles
add_submenu_page( $parent, $p_title, $m_title, 'can_open_coach_menu', 'submenu1');

// this is for administrator and player roles
add_submenu_page( $parent, $p_title, $m_title, 'can_open_player_menu', 'submenu2');
```